# What is the time complexity of an algorithm with the setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Given the following sorting algorithm, what is the time complexity of the `sort`?

```js
function sort(arr) {
  arr.forEach(i => {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i)
  })
}

const n = [100, 1000000, 10000, 3600000, 3, 5, 0, 1, 9];
sort(n);
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
5
9
100
10000
3600000 // After 1 hour
```

Comment: The solution appears to be `O(n)`. However, I am not convinced the `setTimeout` is insignificant. And I also think it's `O(n*nᵢ)`.

Comment: That is a sorting algorithm? lol, I would not be surprised if that would produce invalid results since setTimeout is not really accurate. :)

Comment: @epascarello the algorithm is impractical and unreliable. It's for academic purpose.

Comment: If the question is "time complexity", that is, what drives the overall duration of the function, it's not the number of entries, which is typically denoted by "n" in big-O notation, but rather, it's the max entry.  Eg, sorting [ 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ] where n = 10 will still be ~10x quicker than sorting [ 100 ] where n = 1.  So, I should think the time complexity is directly proportional to the maximum value being sorted, and thus O( max( x) ).

Comment: Actually, the imprecision of setTimeout as nothing to do here, the order must be preserved, so as long as the function's call spans on the same wall clock's ms it's quite reliable. The issue that could arise is if multiple values have less than n-ms of differences and the call to setTimeout for the higher value is done before, e.g `setTimeout( ()=>console.log(2), 2 ); /*....a few ms later because it's a big input */ setTimeout( ()=>console.log(1), 1 );`. Here you'd have 2 logged before 1, because the timeout is relative to call time.